# How to check if a string only contains alphabetic characters in Go?

Tags: go

I am trying to check the username whether is only containing alphabetic characters. What is the idiomatic way to check it in Go?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

you may use [unicode.IsLetter](https://pkg.go.dev/unicode#IsLetter) like this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "unicode"

func IsLetter(s string) bool {
    for _, r := range s {
        if !unicode.IsLetter(r) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsLetter("Alex")) // true
    fmt.Println(IsLetter("123"))  // false
}
```

or if you have limited range e.g. 'a'..'z' and 'A'..'Z', you may use this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func IsLetter(s string) bool {
    for _, r := range s {
        if (r < 'a' || r > 'z') && (r < 'A' || r > 'Z') {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsLetter("Alex"))  // true
    fmt.Println(IsLetter("123 a")) // false

}
```

or if you have limited range e.g. 'a'..'z' and 'A'..'Z', you may use this working sample code:

```
package main

import "fmt"
import "regexp"

var IsLetter = regexp.MustCompile(`^[a-zA-Z]+$`).MatchString

func main() {
    fmt.Println(IsLetter("Alex")) // true
    fmt.Println(IsLetter("u123")) // false
}
```

Comment: Is there a library that provide a set of functions to do string checking?

Comment: @CasperLI : to name a few: strings, fmt, regexp, strconv, unicode, unicode/utf8, unicode/utf16, path/filepath, net/url, bytes, bufio, encoding/json, time,  ...

Comment: @CasperLI To (freely) quote Rob Pike: "A little bit of copying is better than a little more dependency".

Comment: Why there is no a collection of string-checking functions on standard lib or github so that we can directly call those functions in one line?

Comment: Also useful to know a character can be converted to a rune with a regular type conversion `unicode.IsLetter(rune('a'))`

Comment: @Kin A one-liner is possible using `len(strings.TrimFunc(candidateString, unicode.IsLetter)) == 0`

Comment: I particularly like the example where regexp/MustCompile/Match are used on a single line to provide a function that is very description.

Answer (score 13):

Assuming you're only looking for ascii letters, you would normally see this implemented as a regular expression using the alpha character class `[[:alpha:]]` or the equivalent `[A-Za-z]`

```
isAlpha := regexp.MustCompile(`^[A-Za-z]+$`).MatchString

for _, username := range []string{"userone", "user2", "user-three"} {
    if !isAlpha(username) {
        fmt.Printf("%q is not valid\n", username)
    }
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/lT9Fki7tt7

Answer (score 10):

Here's the way I'd do it:

```
import "strings"

const alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

func alphaOnly(s string) bool {
   for _, char := range s {  
      if !strings.Contains(alpha, strings.ToLower(string(char))) {
         return false
      }
   }
   return true
}
```

Comment: `é` is an alphabetic character.

Comment: Shouldn't this be `ContainsAny`?

Answer (score 6):

You can also do this concisely without importing any packages

```
func isLetter(c rune) bool {
    return ('a' <= c && c <= 'z') || ('A' <= c && c <= 'Z')
}

func isWord(s string) bool {
    for _, c := range s {
        if !isLetter(c) {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to use [`FieldsFunc` from Go's `strings` library](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#FieldsFunc).

The following compares each character in the username with the set of unicode letters.  Similar to the `strings.Split` function, `FieldsFunc` splits the username into a slice along boundaries of non-matching characters (in this case, unicode letters).  Below, we compare the original username with the joined elements of the slice.

```
func lettersOnly(username string) bool {
    nonLetter := func(c rune) bool { return !unicode.IsLetter(c) }
    words := strings.FieldsFunc(username, nonLetter)
    return username == strings.Join(words, "")
}
```

Playground Example: https://play.golang.org/p/4aWKCu9upox

We can also compare the username against a list of very specific characters, combining `strings.FieldsFunc` with `strings.ContainsAny`.

```
func hawaiianOnly(username string) bool {
    hawaiian := `aeiouhklmnpwʻ`
    nonCharacter := func(c rune) bool { return !strings.ContainsAny(hawaiian, strings.ToLower(string(c))) }
    words := strings.FieldsFunc(username, nonCharacter)
    return username == strings.Join(words, "")
}
```

Playground Example:https://play.golang.org/p/ipwAOC3c72P

Answer (score 0):

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
    "unicode"
)

func isLetter(c rune) bool {
    return !unicode.IsLetter(c)
}
func main() {
    fmt.Printf(" desired word : %s\n", strings.TrimFunc("12333", isLetter)) //ignored it
    fmt.Printf(" desired word : %s\n", strings.TrimFunc("abcd", isLetter))  //take  it

}
```